# Processing cubes automatically and daily on Microsoft Analysis Services

Tags: ssas

I've followed the steps at the site http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/24960-How-Process-SSAS-Cubes-Automatically.aspx

It works in development phase, but I need to change the target of the cube in deployment environment. 
I opened the package file and I've edited it manually, but it doesn't works...

**I don't know if is authentication problems. But my questions is, how to parametrize the target of the cube that I want to process?**

Thanks.

obs: I'm not expert in Analysis Services but I need to execute this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to, in SSIS, base your Analysis Services connection on an [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141232.aspx):

1. Create a variable @[Server] to hold the name of your Analysis Services server.
2. Add an expression to you Analysis Services connection, pointing the property ServerName to that variable.
3. Add a [Package Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx) to your package, so you can have different configurations according to where you want to deploy the package.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

1. Make a DOMAIN\USER administrator of SQL Server Analysis Services
2. Give the same DOMAIN\USER the fixed-role "sysadmin" on the SQL Server.
3. Create new credentials in SQL Server with Login Data of this DOMAIN\USER.
4. Create a proxy user on SQL Server with the new created credentials, and allow AS Service Command and AS Service Query execution.
5. Create your SQL Server Agent Job that execute a query for cube processing and select the created proxy user.